# jBPM6 in cluster: throw signal in one node, catch it in second

Tags: jbpm

I'm using jBPM 6.3 Final. I have application working in cluster environment with two nodes. I'm using Singleton strategy, with two different ksession (one for each node).

There are two processes:
- first with catch signal "test-signal"
- second with throw signal "test-signal"

Creating first process, and then second process on the same node, the signal is correctly caught by second process.

When I created first process (ksession #1) on first node and then created second process on second node (kesssion #2), the signal is not caught.

1. Is this correct behavior and signals are limited in scope to particular ksession?
2. If yes, what is the best approach to make signal be propagated to all nodes (ksessions)?
3. How can I register a listener for messages/signal or catch event in Java thrown by throw signal node?

Thanks for replays!